# How to set themes globally for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a package with plenty of functions that generate ggplot plots.

At the beginning, I used the default theme for all my plot functions (grey theme) but then I found the black and white theme to be more pleasant to the eye and developed my latest plot functions using that theme.

Is there a way to set the ggplot2 theme globally, i.e. in one place, without having to modify all my plot functions each time I find a new theme I want to apply to all my plots?

Comment: there is `theme_set`

Comment: `?theme_set` / `?theme_update` / `?theme_replace` (they all point to the same manual page)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What I do is to set

```
th <- theme()
```

at the top of my script and then include this to all ggplots. It needs to be added before any plot specific themes or it will overwrite them.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram() + 
  th +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "pink"))
```

At a later stage, you can then change `th` to a different theme

### Edit

`theme_set` and related functions `theme_replace` and `theme_update` suggested by hrbrmstr in the comments are probably better solutions to this problem. They don't require existing code to be edited.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram() + 

g
old <- theme_set(theme_bw()) #capture current theme
g
theme_set(old) #reset theme to previous
```

Comment: you might want to just use `theme_set`

Comment: Whhat if you want the panel.grid.major to be part of the theme as an addition to, say, theme_grey()?

Comment: @jzadra `theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "blue")))`

Comment: Thank you @RichardTelford for the tip. I think this was the best way to do it.

Answer (score 90):

here you go, you should attach the package again

```
 library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
```

Comment: How to add custom settings though, such as panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2ff",colour = NA)

Answer (score 11):

There is now an R-package to set themes globally. https://rstudio.github.io/thematic/

Their example code:

```
library(thematic)
thematic_on(
  bg = "#222222", fg = "white", accent = "#0CE3AC",
  font = font_spec("Oxanium", scale = 1.25)
)
```

After that, each plot inherits these settings.