# How do I change the default plotting parameters for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I frequently make modifications to the ggplot theme when I plot it out for presentation. I typically use something like this:
`theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 24))`
Then for ***every plot*** I have to add code like this:

```
+ theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5)) +
```

Is there any way to add this code *once* as a default? I have looked everywhere I can't seem to find it.

I looked at this answer ([How to set themes globally for ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717154/how-to-set-themes-globally-for-ggplot2)), and there doesn't seem to be a way to add what I am looking for on each plot.

I tried:

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 24))

theme_set(theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
      panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25), 
      panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5)))
```

and it reverts back to the old theme (not theme_bw). I tried this and it gives me an error:

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 24,
                   legend.key.size = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
                   panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25), 
                   panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5)))
```

```
Error in theme_bw(base_size = 24, legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25),  : 
  unused arguments (legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25), panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5))
```

I tried this and it gives me a different error:

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 24))

theme_update(theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
      panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25), 
      panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5)))
```

```
Error in `theme_set()`:
! Problem merging the `line` theme element
Caused by error in `merge_element()`:
! No method for merging <theme> into
  <element_line>
```

I am clearly missing something but I don't know what it is.

Comment: look at `theme_update()`

Comment: Why don't you put the other elements of your custom theme into your `theme_set` call? You're already changing the default base_size parameter? Why not the rest?

Comment: This link doesn't really answer my question. It still seems like you have to add the formatting to each plot. I may not be understanding it though.

Comment: Akrun was mistaken that `theme_bw()` takes more arguments and passes them through to `theme()`. But you can use `+` to add `theme()` customizations to `theme_bw()` (or any other starting theme) inside `theme_set()`: `theme_set(
  theme_bw(base_size = 24) +
    theme(
      legend.key.size = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
      panel.grid.minor = element_line(linewidth = 0.25),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.5)
    )
)
`

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas - that is exactly what I was looking for. The "duplicate" question didn't give me this answer at all. I didn't know you had to use `+` inside the theme_set. Thanks again!

Comment: The key is that `theme_set()` takes any `theme` object. `+` is used modify `theme` objects. It doesn't matter if you do `my_theme = theme(...)` or `my_theme = theme_bw(...) + theme(...)` or use some other method to create a theme.